# Padarn Master Pages (or how do I include .aspx pages)

Tags: asp.net, compact-framework, master-pages, windows-ce, padarn

Does Padarn support the concept of .NET Master Pages and/or the concept of Classic ASP #include?

I would like to reuse my .aspx pages in other .aspx pages as well as implement a single Header & Footer for the web site.

It appears as though Padarn doesn't support .aspx page reuse explicitly and that, maybe, I will need to dynamically generate/call Document objects within a Padarn Page to simulate the Master Page effect.

Before I try to get clever with simulating .aspx reuse within the Padarn framework, I would like to know if there is built-in support for this and/or if there is a best practice for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padarn doesn't have built-in support for master pages or classic ASP syntax.  For page element re-use (headers, footers, menus, etc) we typically use a base class in the code behind where we have methods that can render these elements.  We then derive pages from the base to get the common functionality.